# What if OP had wrong HTML and CSS and my answer got down votes due to his faults?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, browser-support

[Styling inconsistency on Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785711/styling-inconsistency-on-chrome-and-firefox/34875564#34875564)

Above link show my answer. OP wanted help with Firefox being unable to show his wrong HTML and CSS as correct as seen in Chrome. I can see the question itself as duplicate of [Borders not shown in Firefox with border-collapse on table, position: relative on tbody, or background-color on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o). I could not close the question as duplicate as it had open bounty. Then I gave an answer to the question.

As the example was on jsfiddle, and I was using developer tools, I was unable to recreate what I could see in the fiddle at that time and I was in a hurry. Due to lack of time I couldn't show the proper example, but as I open stackoverflow this morning, I could see some down votes and negative reputation. Now I updated my answer with proper jsfiddle link. But still I don't get any attention.

It seems the down votes were cast without proper research, so is there any way, I could get my answer re-evaluated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You state,

> It seems the down votes were cast without proper research

Yet, you state,

> As the example was on jsfiddle, and I was using developer tools, I was unable to recreate what I could see in the fiddle at that time and I was in a hurry. Due to lack of time I couldn't show the proper example

Furthermore, in your answer, you state,

> Although its a duplicate question, I am answering it because it has bounty and cannot be closed.
>
> Check the link:
>
> [Borders not shown in Firefox with border-collapse on table, position: relative on tbody, or background-color on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517127/borders-not-shown-in-firefox-with-border-collapse-on-table-position-relative-o)

So if I were to hazard a guess, the downvotes could have been a reaction to you knowingly posting a low-quality answer to a duplicate question with a bounty. That could be seen as an attempt at sniping a bounty and the downvotes could have been to make sure you couldn't earn the bounty for such a low-quality answer. You talk about research, but it's not clear what sort of research you expect readers, let alone voters, to do.

Sure, you've edited your answer now. But it may very well be too late. Those who downvoted your answer before might or might not see it again, and those who do might or might not be inclined to change their votes. You can't control this. You can only take this as a lesson not to post half-baked answers, especially not to questions with a bounty where the quality bar is much, much higher than the usual.

If you want to address the faults in the question leading to the observed behavior, do so. Don't chastise voters for not doing their research, don't whine about getting downvoted, just answer the question (and actually do so — don't just post a duplicate link without answering the question).

Comment: Ok if that was the case, then what about the reputation deduction due to poor quality example itself?

Comment: What do you mean what about it?

Comment: I tried to flag the question, but I was not let to do so as it had bounty. In that case should I let go the question as it was?

Comment: Can I delete my answer and get back my reputation penalty?

Comment: @kiran: Yes, you can and you will get back any reputation that was lost to downvotes.

Comment: ok, as I am still new to this community, I would take this as a lession. Thank you.